# Using block - scope issues

Tags: vb.net, using-statement

I am learning visual basic and OOP on the fly.
This piece of code displays the query results to a combo box on a form...

```
Dim c = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("db").ToString()
Dim daDogs As New SqlDataAdapter ("select dog_type from humane_society with(nolock)",c)
Dim dtdogs As New DataTable
dadogs.Fill(dtdogs)
cboDogs.DataSource = dtdogs
cboDogs.DisplayMember = "dog_type"

when I change it to use a Using block, the combo box is blank
I think it is a scope issue, but I don't know how to fix it.  Any productive suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Dim c = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("db").ToString()
Using cDog As New SqlConnection(c)
      Using cmd As New SqlCommand("select dog_type from humane_society with(nolock)",cDog)
            cmd.CommandType = commandtype.Text
            Using daDogs As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                  Using dtDogs As New Datatable`enter code here`
                        daDogs.Fill(dtDogs)
'                            MsgBox(dtMunic.Rows(500).Field(of string)(0))
                        cboDogs.DataSource = dtDogs
                        cboDogs.DisplayMember = "dog_type"
                  End Using
            End Using
      End Using
End Using
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: What changes do I need in my code to get the Using block to work?  The msgbox I have in the using block shows me that the dataTable is populated, but when I tie it to the combobox, the box is blank on the form.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what that message box is doing in your code. Remember that a message box halts the code until the user responds. You connection, among other things, is open while the code waits.

You are correct that items declared in a block are scoped to that block.

I have separated your database code from your user interface code.

You can save using blocks by adding a comma and combining more than one object in the block. Behaves the same, just makes the code a bit easier to read.

```
Private ConStr As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("db").ToString() '"Your connection string"

Private Function GetDogData() As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cDog As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("select dog_type from humane_society with(nolock)", cDog)
        cDog.Open()
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dt.Load(reader)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dtDogs = GetDogData()
    cboDogs.DataSource = dtDogs
    cboDogs.DisplayMember = "dog_type"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Mary, I appreciate your comments and the clean up of my code!  I accidentally came across LINQ.  Someone tells me that is easier to use. Yay!